# express post data to mongoosedb but return 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, express

I am posting a data to mongoosedb, I check my code seems no bug or typo, but when I send data through `app.post()` , it return 400, I check the data can connect to post `app.post()`, because I change the return error 400 to 401, the browser say the error is 401.

return error set to 400
`POST http://localhost:3000/api/products 400 (Bad Request)`

return error set to 401
`POST http://localhost:3000/api/products 401 (Unauthorized)`

I sure that the db has been connected, because I set something like this

```
mongoose.connect('<MY key for mongodb>')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB Atlas!');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas!');
    console.error(error);
});
```

It return `Successfully connected to MongoDB Atlas!` when I connect.

what will be the bug?

`app.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Product = require('./models/product');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/products', (req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
        inStock: req.body.inStock,
        userId: req.body.userId
    });
    product.save().then(
        () => {
          res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Post saved successfully!'
          });
        }
      ).catch(
        (error) => {
          res.status(400).json({
            error: error
          });
        }
      );
});
```

`product.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  inStock: { type: Boolean, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

that the code for requesting data from db

```
app.use('/api/stuff', (req, res, next) => {
  Thing.find().then(
    (things) => {
      res.status(200).json(things);
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: You are returning an `error` with the 400 response, what does it say?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts `POST http://localhost:3000/api/products 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: In the catch block you are using [res.json](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json), which returns a JSON object with the response. You are passing the `error` you get from the database with it. What does it say? You could also `console.log` the error on the server.

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts {"error":{"errors":{"userId":{"name":"ValidatorError","message":"Path `userId` is required.","properties":{"message":"Path `userId` is required.","type":"required","path":"userId"},"kind":"required","path":"userId"}},"_message":"Product validation failed","name":"ValidationError","message":"Product validation failed: userId: Path `userId` is required."}}

Comment: Are you including `userId` in the request to this endpoint?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts endpoint mean the db struct?

Comment: The API endpoint `/api/products`.

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts not sure

Comment: How are you making the request?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts using `post` for new product, `get` for get a single product, `put` for update or delete, `use` for geting all data

Comment: How are you making the `POST` request to `/api/products`? Are you passing all of the data the error is telling you is required?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts I did't set up the input data, I got the guideline to set up the db product item, and got a HTML file with a button, when pressed, it sends data in the db. and return the result 

//How are you making the `POST` request to /api/products?
I have no idea about this question

Comment: You need to take a look at the code called when you press the button and make sure that all of the fields that are required are included.